# Is it possible to import functions in c++?

Tags: c++

I have two programs given below in two separate files in c++.

File A.cpp

```cpp
void name(){
cin>>name;
}
```

File B.cpp

```cpp
void age(){
cin>>age;
}
```

Now, I need to use the function `name` in file B. Can I do it without rewriting the entire function (`name`) in file `B.cpp`? Can I import functions in C++, just like you do in other languages, such as JavaScript?

Comment: Do you have a `B.h` file that declares `age` in it?

Comment: Can we declare functions in .h files in c++? I am sorry, but I am new to c++, so I don't have much idea about it? Can you please explain your answer?

Comment: Yes, you can declare functions in a header file.  All declarations should go there unless you want them to be "private".  Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: You can read a bit about it [here](https://yact.tech/en/posts/05_declarations_and_definitions_I.html) and [here](https://yact.tech/en/posts/06_declarations_and_definitions_II.html).

Comment: I would look at the answer provided in this post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25274312/is-it-a-good-practice-to-define-c-functions-inside-header-files

Answer (score 1):

Create a header file containing a declaration for the `name()` function, and then you can `#include` that header in any source file that needs to access `name()`, eg:

A.h

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H

void name();

#endif
```

A.cpp

```cpp
#include "A.h"

void name(){
    ...
}
```

B.cpp

```cpp
#include "A.h"

void age(){
    ...
    name();
    ...
}
```

Comment: Maybe add to the answer, that all `.cpp` files must be compiled independently, and in a final step linked together into a executable binary.